# Spacing before and after \color{}

Tags: spacing, color

I want to define a command, `\makered`, that makes things red. Consider three candidates:

`1`: `\newcommand{\makered}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}`

`2`: `\newcommand{\makered}[1]{\colorlet{savedcol}{.}\color{red}#1\color{savedcol}}`

`3`: `\newcommand{\makered}[1]{\colorlet{savedcol}{.}\color{red}#1 \color{savedcol}}`

Both have their own drawbacks. For example, with `1`, when we run

```
\begin{gather*}
\text{A \makered{is} B}\\
A\makered{=}B\\
A=B
\end{gather*}
```

we will get

[image]

which shows the wrong spacing around `mathrel`.

But with `2`, we will instead get

[image]

which shows the wrong spacing after `text`.

`3` solves all these problems, but if we run

```
\begin{gather*}
\underbrace{\text{A}}\\
\underbrace{\text{\makered{A}}}
\end{gather*}
```

we will get

[image]

Is there an alternative solution, or a way to fix this?

---

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\makered}[1]{\colorlet{cb@saved}{.}\color{red}#1 \color{cb@saved}}
\newcommand{\makered}[1]{{\color{red} #1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\text{A \makered{is} B}\\
A\makered{=}B\\
A=B\\
\underbrace{\text{A}}\\
\underbrace{\text{\makered{A}}}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: in current releases use `\mathcolor{red}{...}` which will get the math spacing right

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you sure that you really want to use `color`? This macro is a toggle, which is maybe not the best option here.

Simply use `\textcolor{red}{some text}` in text mode, and `\mathcolor{red}{some math}` in math mode. The latter will handle spacing properly.

Comment: Thanks! I checked how `\mathcolor` is defined, and use it to come up with the following solution: `\newcommand{\makered}[1]{\protect\leavevmode\begingroup\color{red}#1\endgroup}`

Comment: textcolor is equivalent to your definition (1) and will lose math spacing as you demonstrated. you can use \mathcolor on current releases @user182849

Comment: @user182849 Maybe I missed something, but I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve with this macro... What does it bring that standard commands `\textcolor` and `\mathcolor` don't already do?

Comment: @Miyase possibly The OP has an old latex release, and does not easily have `\mathcolor` available (it was added this year)

Comment: Yes. (1) I have an old latex release and (2) I want to move expressions back and forth between mathmode and textmode, so need a command that works in both modes.

Answer (score 3):

Your second attempt is almost correct. But the LaTeX's `\color{...}` runs `\ignorespaces` primitive at its end. You have to deactivate it, for example by `\relax`:

```
\newcommand{\makered}[1]{\colorlet{savedcol}{.}\color{red}#1\color{savedcol}\relax}
```

Another approach. Use idea from your first attempt but don't use `\bgroup`, `\group` pair (i.e. `{...}`) becaue it creates the Ord atom in math typesetting. Use `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`. It allocates the group too, but doesn't create the Ord atom:

```
\def\makered#1{\begingroup\color{red}#1\endgroup}
```

Comment: Good to know why my attempts don't work, and why `\newcommand{\makered}[1]{\protect\leavevmode\begingroup\color{red}#1\endgroup}` works! Thanks!!